# Spring Boot not serving Vite dist/prod build assets, only index.html

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, vite

I have a Java Spring Boot backend, with a Tomcat server configured.

I have a React frontend, packaged using Vite, with "vite build" sending everything to a "dist" directory.

I move this "dist" directory to my "src/main/resources/static/" directory to be served automatically by Spring. This is running in a Docker container.

I'm able to pull up my home page. However, the front-end isn't picking up any CSS packaged by Vite, despite the fact I can see it in the `dist` folder under `dist/assets/*`, and the path in my `dist/index.html` to that `assets/index-${HASH}.css` file is correct.

**This is only happening on sub-routes from index.html in my app.** It's worth noting that when I refresh the page, I get a **"Whitelabel Error Page"**. It's like my app doesn't recognize that, for example, `https://localhost/route/routetwo` is supposed to be a persistent path from the entrypoint `index.html`.

What's weird about this, and making it hard to troubleshoot, is that everything works correctly when running `vite preview` in a different Docker container. I'm able to see the child routes with the correct CSS, refreshing the page with no issue, etc.

In "Developer Tools -> Sources" I see the contents of `index.html` for the sub-route when running `vite preview`, but not when trying to serve it as part of Spring. It's something about how Spring is interacting with my vite build.

Any ideas?

I've tried numerous things, including but not limited to:

- Pulling the dist out of the `vite preview` container, pasting it into my backend `src/main/resources/static` directory and serving it that way rather than building dynamically with each Docker container. No dice, still not finding my `/assets/index-${HASH}.css`
- Doing the same as the above, but moving `assets/*` out of the assets directory and into the same directory as `src/main/resources/static/index.html`, changing the pathing in `index.html`. No result.
- Considerable testing to make sure it's not a directory issue with my Docker builds. Confirmed there's basically no difference between the successful container and the unsuccessful except one is using `vite preview` and the other is using Spring static asset serving.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ? I'm interested in your solutiono if you have any